# SSIS Script Component + Helper Assemblies (.dll's)

Tags: ssis, scripting, components, gac

I got a script component which does Transformation / DataType conversions / Creating some calculated columns.  All the transform validations / datatype conversion methods and for new column generation is put into custom .dll.

As this script component would be same for all other tables, only thing is to define input / ouput columns and apply validation methods on required columns.

This all works fine.  On production server where do I need to deploy my .dll.

Would just putting it into GAC will be enough or need to do something else.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You just need the DLL GAC'ed on the SQL box that runs the package.

Check out the SSIS deployment guide...

PK  :-)